# Upgrade method for fieldtypes (add-on development)

Tags: add-on-development

Has anyone written an upgrade for a fieldtype? I'm assuming so, but I've not actually ventured this direction, and there are zero docs in this arena.

Specifically in this case, upgrading a fieldtype with no settings to have per-field settings, which will update the fieldtype preferences in the DB etc etc.

Direction? Hacky style required?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's something difficult for me to write everything here related to field type update :). let me try to give you some pointer.

While creating a field type, you were creating a $info array having "name" and "version". If you are going to update you field type, first step will be to higher the "version" value within the $info array.

Second thing: the field type file will have a function update like:

```
function update($from)
{
if($from < 2.0){
[process the stuffs which you need to update in the updated version of 2.0 in the case your previous version was less than 2.0]
}
}
```

Now it's depend on you, what you would like to update. If you would like to update the settings or field type display then you will need to modify the code within their function. In the update function you can re-structure database related stuffs.

I hope, my little pointer will help you.

Best Regards,

Comment: So the ft.whatever.php supports `update()`? Since this stuff is serialized, are there helpers somewhere to push this data around or am i on my own? I can write whatever, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel here.

Answer (score 1):

Although it isn't documented BKY is right, fieldtypes can have `update()` methods. Here's the relevant bit of code from addons_fieldtypes.php:

```
// Update if version changed
$version = $installed[$ft]['version'];

if ($FT->info['version'] > $version && method_exists($FT, 'update') && $FT->update($version) !== FALSE)
{
    $this->db->update('fieldtypes', array('version' => $FT->info['version']), array('name' => $ft));
}
```

As with other `update()` methods you should return `TRUE` if the update was a success and `FALSE` if it's failed.

```
function update($from)
{
    if ($from == MY_ADDON_CURRENT_VERSION) return FALSE;

    if (version_compare($from, '1.1', '<'))
    {
        // Update Stuff
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

I'd be happy to be proven wrong but don't think there are any helpers for retrieving/updating FT settings. You'd need to do all of the querying/serializing/base64 encoding* yourself.

<sub>* Why, EllisLab, why?</sub>

Comment: When is this update function actually called?

Comment: As far as I can see, only when the fieldtype settings page is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the update method is available, BUT it's only triggered if you visit the global settings for the fieldtype.

Unfortunately, if you create a feildtype which doesn't have global settings, you're kinda boned and will have to find a workaround for querying/updating the installed version in the database and setting 'has_global_settings' to 'y' in exp_fieldtypes.

Such a PITA.